# I want to generate iOS push notification payload with badge and sound features, what classes and libraries can I use? [c#]

Tags: c#, ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Apple Notification Class does not appear to have properties for badge and sound :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.applenotification.aspx

Is there some other class that could generate an iOS payload with sound and badge. I know I can do it manually by making strings, but would prefer to use a created class..

For example , this is undesired:

```
var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + pushNotificationMessage + "\",\"badge\":<input1>,\"sound\": <input2>"}}";
```

This would be better :

```
microsoftDefinedMethod( message = null, badge = false, sound = false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt420961.aspx) method (or one of its overloads):

```
public Task<NotificationOutcome> SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(string jsonPayload)
```

The `jsonPayload` parameter is the [native iOS payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html). Here's an example from the official documentation that looks like something you want to achieve:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

Also, there's an slightly different question on SO with [an answer that has a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26492433/182371) potentially similar to what you'd write in your case.

Comment: However, there is no method to generate JsonPayloads strings , correct ? I would have to create a method myself to organize the alert, badge, sound, and anything else I would want ?

Comment: No, there's no built-in method to generate the payload. But it's just a string. You can use a `string.Format(...)` template to generate those. Or do it [the way they did it in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26492433/182371) I linked to.